# IsSelected style in DataTemplate,Triggers does not apply

Tags: c#, wpf

Please find the below code. I have used itemscontrol and data template.
Inside data template, i have grid and borders which i needed. 
I have written styles for datatemplate using DataTemplate.Triggers.
Style is applied for mouseover but style is not applied for Isselected.
How to achieve isselected style???
  Xaml:

```html
<ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="lvDataBinding">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>         
                        <Grid Margin="10,0,5,0" Width="500">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="120*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="120*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="120*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="120*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="FirstSelectionBorder" BorderBrush="#FF0087AA" >
                                <Border x:Name="FirstNormalBorder" BorderBrush="#FF555555" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Grid x:Name="FirstGrid">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="300*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="23"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Code" Foreground="#FF555555" FontSize="10"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content=":" Foreground="#FF555555" FontSize="10"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="#FF555555" FontSize="10" />
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Text="Serial Number" Foreground="#FF555555" FontSize="10"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Content=":" Foreground="#FF555555" FontSize="10"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Age}" Foreground="#FF555555" FontSize="10"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Text="Age" Foreground="#FF555555" FontSize="10"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Content=":" Foreground="#FF555555" FontSize="10"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Mail}" Foreground="#FF555555" FontSize="10"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Button x:Name="OKButton" Grid.Column="3"  Content="OK" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,10" >
    
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button x:Name="Cancelbutton" Grid.Column="5"  Content="Cancel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,10">
    
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button x:Name="FirstDeleteButton" Grid.Column="6"  VerticalAlignment="top" Margin="3,5,2,0" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>                          
                              </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="FirstNormalBorder" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="FirstNormalBorder" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

```
cs:
 public MainWindow()
        {        
            InitializeComponent();

            List<User> items = new List<User>();
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com" });
            lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
        }

    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Mail { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ItemsControl` does not track SelectedItem. You can use `ListBox`

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         Name="lvDataBinding">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <!-- Removes default blue background for selected item -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Transparent" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="10,0,5,0"
                  Width="500">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="120*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="120*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="120*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="120*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="FirstSelectionBorder"
                        BorderBrush="#FF0087AA">
                    <Border x:Name="FirstNormalBorder"
                            BorderBrush="#FF555555"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid x:Name="FirstGrid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
                                           Text="Code"
                                           Foreground="#FF555555"
                                           FontSize="10" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="3"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Content=":"
                                       Foreground="#FF555555"
                                       FontSize="10" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           Foreground="#FF555555"
                                           FontSize="10" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5"
                                           Text="Serial Number"
                                           Foreground="#FF555555"
                                           FontSize="10" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="5"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Content=":"
                                       Foreground="#FF555555"
                                       FontSize="10" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Text="{Binding Age}"
                                           Foreground="#FF555555"
                                           FontSize="10" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="7"
                                           Text="Age"
                                           Foreground="#FF555555"
                                           FontSize="10" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="7"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Content=":"
                                       Foreground="#FF555555"
                                       FontSize="10" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="7"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Text="{Binding Mail}"
                                           Foreground="#FF555555"
                                           FontSize="10" />
                            </Grid>
                            <Button x:Name="OKButton"
                                    Grid.Column="3"
                                    Content="OK"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,10">

                            </Button>
                            <Button x:Name="Cancelbutton"
                                    Grid.Column="5"
                                    Content="Cancel"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,10">

                            </Button>
                            <Button x:Name="FirstDeleteButton"
                                    Grid.Column="6"
                                    VerticalAlignment="top"
                                    Margin="3,5,2,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </Grid>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="FirstNormalBorder"
                            Property="Background"
                            Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={
                    RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem }}}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="FirstNormalBorder" Property="Background"
                            Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>

            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```